# How to print two pagelayout on two sides at the same time ?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I am having a PageLayoutControl with name: PageControl1. I used below codes for printing it:

```
public override void OnClick()
 {
                try
                {
                    PrintDialog printDiag = new PrintDialog();
                    DialogResult res = printDiag.ShowDialog();
                    if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
                        return;

                    ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.IPaper paper = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.PaperClass();
                    paper.Attach(printDiag.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode().ToInt32(), printDiag.PrinterSettings.GetHdevnames().ToInt32());
                    paper.Orientation = PageControl1.PageLayout .Page .Orientation ;
                    PageControl1.Printer.Paper = paper;
                    PageControl1.PrintPageLayout(1, 1, 0);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message , null, MessageBoxButtons .OK , MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation );
                }

 }
```

And I have another PageLayoutControl with name: PageControl2. Do you know how to print these PageLayoutControl on two sides of one paper (only one click printing button) ? (PageControl1 on the front side, PageControl2 on the back side) ?

Thanks and regards,